# OpenVPN Client on Windows Server 2012 is not able to change routing

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, routing, openvpn

I have a Virtual Windows 2012 Server that runs some Internet-Communication Software which requires me to change the IP-range once. It doesn't matter whether this is secure or not, this is just test software and nothing serious is done on the server.

My problem is that I can't get OpenVPN to work on the server.
For test purposes, I just chose any public free VPN, such as from freevpn.me

My openvpn.log for the freevpn.me connection looks as follows:

```
Fri Feb 17 07:13:23 2017 OpenVPN 2.4.0 x86_64-w64-mingw32 [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [PKCS11] [AEAD] built on Jan 31 2017
Fri Feb 17 07:13:23 2017 Windows version 6.2 (Windows 8 or greater) 64bit
Fri Feb 17 07:13:23 2017 library versions: OpenSSL 1.0.2k  26 Jan 2017, LZO 2.09
Enter Management Password:
Fri Feb 17 07:13:23 2017 MANAGEMENT: TCP Socket listening on [AF_INET]127.0.0.1:25340
Fri Feb 17 07:13:23 2017 Need hold release from management interface, waiting...
Fri Feb 17 07:13:23 2017 MANAGEMENT: Client connected from [AF_INET]127.0.0.1:25340
Fri Feb 17 07:13:23 2017 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'state on'
Fri Feb 17 07:13:23 2017 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'log all on'
Fri Feb 17 07:13:23 2017 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'hold off'
Fri Feb 17 07:13:23 2017 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'hold release'
Fri Feb 17 07:13:40 2017 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'username "Auth" "freevpnme"'
Fri Feb 17 07:13:40 2017 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'password [...]'
Fri Feb 17 07:13:40 2017 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'proxy HTTP 172.22.1.3 3128'
Fri Feb 17 07:13:41 2017 WARNING: No server certificate verification method has been enabled.  See http://openvpn.net/howto.html#mitm for more info.
Fri Feb 17 07:13:41 2017 NOTE: --fast-io is disabled since we are running on Windows
Fri Feb 17 07:13:41 2017 TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]172.22.1.3:3128
Fri Feb 17 07:13:41 2017 Socket Buffers: R=[65536->65536] S=[65536->65536]
Fri Feb 17 07:13:41 2017 Attempting to establish TCP connection with [AF_INET]172.22.1.3:3128 [nonblock]
Fri Feb 17 07:13:41 2017 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1487312021,TCP_CONNECT,,,,,,
Fri Feb 17 07:13:42 2017 TCP connection established with [AF_INET]172.22.1.3:3128
Fri Feb 17 07:13:42 2017 Send to HTTP proxy: 'CONNECT 212.129.33.61:443 HTTP/1.0'
Fri Feb 17 07:13:42 2017 Send to HTTP proxy: 'Host: 212.129.33.61'
Fri Feb 17 07:13:42 2017 HTTP proxy returned: 'HTTP/1.0 200 Connection established'
Fri Feb 17 07:13:44 2017 TCP_CLIENT link local: (not bound)
Fri Feb 17 07:13:44 2017 TCP_CLIENT link remote: [AF_INET]172.22.1.3:3128
Fri Feb 17 07:13:44 2017 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1487312024,WAIT,,,,,,
Fri Feb 17 07:13:44 2017 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1487312024,AUTH,,,,,,
Fri Feb 17 07:13:44 2017 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]172.22.1.3:3128, sid=ad1adcd1 b2b7cd7a
Fri Feb 17 07:13:44 2017 WARNING: this configuration may cache passwords in memory -- use the auth-nocache option to prevent this
Fri Feb 17 07:13:44 2017 VERIFY OK: depth=1, C=MT, ST=MLT, L=Valletta, O=FreeVPN.me, OU=FreeVPN.me, CN=FreeVPN.me CA, name=FreeVPN.me, emailAddress=contact@freevpn.me
Fri Feb 17 07:13:44 2017 VERIFY OK: depth=0, C=MT, ST=MLT, L=Valletta, O=FreeVPN.me, OU=FreeVPN.me, CN=FreeVPN.me, name=FreeVPN.me, emailAddress=contact@freevpn.me
Fri Feb 17 07:13:45 2017 Control Channel: TLSv1.2, cipher TLSv1/SSLv3 DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, 2048 bit RSA
Fri Feb 17 07:13:45 2017 [FreeVPN.me] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]172.22.1.3:3128
Fri Feb 17 07:13:46 2017 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1487312026,GET_CONFIG,,,,,,
Fri Feb 17 07:13:46 2017 SENT CONTROL [FreeVPN.me]: 'PUSH_REQUEST' (status=1)
Fri Feb 17 07:13:46 2017 PUSH: Received control message: 'PUSH_REPLY,redirect-gateway def1,dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8,dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4,route 10.13.0.1,topology net30,ping 10,ping-restart 60,ifconfig 10.13.1.110 10.13.1.109'
Fri Feb 17 07:13:46 2017 OPTIONS IMPORT: timers and/or timeouts modified
Fri Feb 17 07:13:46 2017 OPTIONS IMPORT: --ifconfig/up options modified
Fri Feb 17 07:13:46 2017 OPTIONS IMPORT: route options modified
Fri Feb 17 07:13:46 2017 OPTIONS IMPORT: --ip-win32 and/or --dhcp-option options modified
Fri Feb 17 07:13:46 2017 Data Channel Encrypt: Cipher 'AES-128-CBC' initialized with 128 bit key
Fri Feb 17 07:13:46 2017 Data Channel Encrypt: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Fri Feb 17 07:13:46 2017 Data Channel Decrypt: Cipher 'AES-128-CBC' initialized with 128 bit key
Fri Feb 17 07:13:46 2017 Data Channel Decrypt: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Fri Feb 17 07:13:46 2017 interactive service msg_channel=0
Fri Feb 17 07:13:46 2017 ROUTE_GATEWAY 172.22.1.1/255.255.255.0 I=12 HWADDR=00:50:56:98:74:d6
Fri Feb 17 07:13:46 2017 open_tun
Fri Feb 17 07:13:46 2017 TAP-WIN32 device [Ethernet] opened: \\.\Global\{3EFF9323-DB9B-45CF-A89F-E8E2637975E4}.tap
Fri Feb 17 07:13:46 2017 TAP-Windows Driver Version 9.21 
Fri Feb 17 07:13:46 2017 Notified TAP-Windows driver to set a DHCP IP/netmask of 10.13.1.110/255.255.255.252 on interface {3EFF9323-DB9B-45CF-A89F-E8E2637975E4} [DHCP-serv: 10.13.1.109, lease-time: 31536000]
Fri Feb 17 07:13:46 2017 Successful ARP Flush on interface [15] {3EFF9323-DB9B-45CF-A89F-E8E2637975E4}
Fri Feb 17 07:13:46 2017 do_ifconfig, tt->did_ifconfig_ipv6_setup=0
Fri Feb 17 07:13:46 2017 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1487312026,ASSIGN_IP,,10.13.1.110,,,,
Fri Feb 17 07:13:48 2017 TEST ROUTES: 2/2 succeeded len=1 ret=1 a=0 u/d=up
Fri Feb 17 07:13:48 2017 C:\Windows\system32\route.exe ADD 172.22.1.3 MASK 255.255.255.255 172.22.1.1 IF 12
Fri Feb 17 07:13:48 2017 ROUTE: CreateIpForwardEntry succeeded with dwForwardMetric1=5 and dwForwardType=4
Fri Feb 17 07:13:48 2017 Route addition via IPAPI succeeded [adaptive]
Fri Feb 17 07:13:48 2017 C:\Windows\system32\route.exe ADD 0.0.0.0 MASK 128.0.0.0 10.13.1.109
Fri Feb 17 07:13:48 2017 ROUTE: CreateIpForwardEntry succeeded with dwForwardMetric1=20 and dwForwardType=4
Fri Feb 17 07:13:48 2017 Route addition via IPAPI succeeded [adaptive]
Fri Feb 17 07:13:48 2017 C:\Windows\system32\route.exe ADD 128.0.0.0 MASK 128.0.0.0 10.13.1.109
Fri Feb 17 07:13:48 2017 ROUTE: CreateIpForwardEntry succeeded with dwForwardMetric1=20 and dwForwardType=4
Fri Feb 17 07:13:48 2017 Route addition via IPAPI succeeded [adaptive]
Fri Feb 17 07:13:48 2017 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1487312028,ADD_ROUTES,,,,,,
Fri Feb 17 07:13:48 2017 C:\Windows\system32\route.exe ADD 10.13.0.1 MASK 255.255.255.255 10.13.1.109
Fri Feb 17 07:13:48 2017 ROUTE: CreateIpForwardEntry succeeded with dwForwardMetric1=20 and dwForwardType=4
Fri Feb 17 07:13:48 2017 Route addition via IPAPI succeeded [adaptive]
Fri Feb 17 07:13:48 2017 Initialization Sequence Completed
Fri Feb 17 07:13:48 2017 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1487312028,CONNECTED,SUCCESS,10.13.1.110,172.22.1.3,3128,172.22.1.193,52553
```

This is my routing table after VPN is connected:

```
C:\>route print
===========================================================================
Schnittstellenliste
 15...00 ff 3e ff 93 23 ......TAP-Windows Adapter V9
 12...00 50 56 98 74 d6 ......vmxnet3 Ethernet Adapter #3
1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
 13...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft-ISATAP-Adapter
 14...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
 28...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft-ISATAP-Adapter #2
===========================================================================

IPv4-Routentabelle
===========================================================================
Aktive Routen:
   Netzwerkziel    Netzwerkmaske          Gateway    Schnittstelle Metrik
        0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0       172.22.1.1     172.22.1.193    261
        0.0.0.0        128.0.0.0        10.9.0.33      10.13.1.110     20
        0.0.0.0        128.0.0.0      10.13.1.109      10.13.1.110     20
       10.9.0.1  255.255.255.255        10.9.0.33      10.13.1.110     20
      10.13.0.1  255.255.255.255      10.13.1.109      10.13.1.110     20
    10.13.1.108  255.255.255.252   Auf Verbindung       10.13.1.110    276
    10.13.1.110  255.255.255.255   Auf Verbindung       10.13.1.110    276
    10.13.1.111  255.255.255.255   Auf Verbindung       10.13.1.110    276
      127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0   Auf Verbindung         127.0.0.1    306
      127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255   Auf Verbindung         127.0.0.1    306
127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255   Auf Verbindung         127.0.0.1    306
      128.0.0.0        128.0.0.0        10.9.0.33      10.13.1.110     20
      128.0.0.0        128.0.0.0      10.13.1.109      10.13.1.110     20
     172.22.1.0    255.255.255.0   Auf Verbindung      172.22.1.193    261
     172.22.1.3  255.255.255.255       172.22.1.1     172.22.1.193      5
   172.22.1.193  255.255.255.255   Auf Verbindung      172.22.1.193    261
   172.22.1.255  255.255.255.255   Auf Verbindung      172.22.1.193    261
      224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0   Auf Verbindung         127.0.0.1    306
      224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0   Auf Verbindung       10.13.1.110    276
      224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0   Auf Verbindung      172.22.1.193    261
255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255   Auf Verbindung         127.0.0.1    306
255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255   Auf Verbindung       10.13.1.110    276
255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255   Auf Verbindung      172.22.1.193    261
===========================================================================
Ständige Routen:
Netzwerkadresse          Netzmaske  Gatewayadresse  Metrik
        0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0       172.22.1.1  Standard
===========================================================================

IPv6-Routentabelle
===========================================================================
Aktive Routen:
 If Metrik Netzwerkziel             Gateway
1    306 ::1/128                  Auf Verbindung
 15    276 fe80::/64                Auf Verbindung
 12    261 fe80::/64                Auf Verbindung
 12    261 fe80::1dca:d314:3e09:82ae/128
                                  Auf Verbindung
 15    276 fe80::20c6:40f9:7577:57df/128
                                  Auf Verbindung
1    306 ff00::/8                 Auf Verbindung
 15    276 ff00::/8                 Auf Verbindung
 12    261 ff00::/8                 Auf Verbindung
===========================================================================
Ständige Routen:
Keine

C:\>
```

If I go to ifconfig.me, it says my IP address is still 141.76.15.132

What I tried so far:

- run OpenVPN as Administrator
- change DNS-Servers to 8.8.8.8/8.8.4.4 (google)
- disable/enable Firewall

I have no clue why this isn't working.

But I am not sure how I can integrate these solutions with my OpenVPN setup.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

---

Edit on 2017-02-20

I am a little bit further. So the connection seems to get established, but Windows 2012 is still using the original Ethernet adapter and I can't change the order of the two:

[Netstat shows two nic's, TAP V9 is the OpenVPN adapter and vmxnet3 the original one. The latter has an assigned prioity of 12, wheras OpenVPN is 15 (lower). Manually setting metric for both in Ethernet connection doesn't help (see left image, netstat).
I also tried changing the order of Ethernet NICs, OpenVPN (top of the list) should get accessed first. This doesn't work either (see right image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WaswE.jpg)

[This is the Network & Sharing, as you can see, traffic is only going through "Ethernet0 4"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02K8W.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 2 more days of searching, I found a solution:

I had to disable the system proxy after establishing the VPN, otherwise it seems that traffic was routed over the VPN back to the proxy.

[Disabled System proxy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6twPk.jpg)

What made me suspicious was that, after establishing the VPN, the tracert command would show a route over the VPN back to the proxy to the final address. After disabling the proxy while VPN is established, a tracert would route directly over to VPN to the destination.

Just add the proxy to OpenVPN Settings and disable it in-system. This way, the virtual machine will only be able to connect to the internet if OpenVPN session is running.